# Dynamic UI with googlevis plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I am having a bit of an issue trying to get a dynamic UI to work with googlevis. Essentially I want to allow a user to input a range of interest with a slider bar and the plot to change accordingly. In the following example I've used data sets from the googlevis package to illustrate what I mean. If you run the code below you will get no errors, however no plots are produced:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons('data_choice', 'choose a dataset', 
                   choices= c('dataset1', 'dataset2')),
      uiOutput('slider')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput('view')

    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(ggplot2)

dataset1= dino
dataset2= Fruits[,c(1,6)]

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Output new slider depending on dataset chosen
  output$slider<- renderUI({
    if(input$data_choice== 'dataset1'){
      sliderInput('rangeSlider', 'Choose data range',
                  min= 0, max= max(dataset1$Length),
                  value= c(0, max(dataset1$Length)))

    }else if(input$data_choice== 'dataset2'){
      sliderInput('rangeSlider', 'Choose data range',
                  min= 0, max= max(dataset2$Profit),
                  value= c(0, max(dataset2$Profit)))
    }
  })

  #plot adjust
  adjustPlot<- reactive({
    #Adjust dataframes based on input from slider

    if(input$data_choice== 'dataset1'){
      adjusted_dataset1<- subset(dataset1, 
                                 Length >= input$rangeSlider[1] & Length <= input$rangeSlider[2])

    }else if(input$data_choice== 'dataset2'){
      adjusted_dataset2<- subset(dataset2, 
                                 Profit >= input$rangeSlider[1] & Profit <= input$rangeSlider[2])
    }

  })

  output$view <- renderGvis({
    gvisBarChart(adjustPlot(), options= list(height= 700))
  })

})
```

If you replace the output with a ggplot plot and not googlevis the code runs fine.

**ui.R**

```
mainPanel(
      plotOutput('view')
    )
```

**server.R**

```
  #ggplot that works 
  output$view <- renderPlot({
    if(input$data_choice=='dataset1'){
      p<-ggplot(adjustPlot(), aes(x=Dinosaur, y=Length)) 
      p<-p + geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='navyblue') + coord_flip()

    }else if(input$data_choice=='dataset2') {
      p<-ggplot(adjustPlot(), aes(x=Fruit, y=Profit)) 
      p<-p + geom_bar(stat='identity', fill= 'forestgreen') + coord_flip()

    } 

    print(p)

  }, height=550)
```

It seems as though there is an issue with the rendering of the google plot to the application when taken inputs from renderUI (perhaps because it renders it as html..). Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem as though this issue was too popular, but because of how much time I spent trying to solve it I figured I'd post my answer with the hope that it can help someone down the road. There was two problems with the original code that I still do not fully understand, but I imagine they are due to the javascript generated by the gvis plot.

First, the input variables in `renderUI()` must be distinct for the two conditions (renderSlider1 and renderSlider2):

**server.R**

```
#Output new slider depending on interested paramter chosen
  output$slider<- renderUI({
    if(input$data_choice== 'dataset1'){
      sliderInput('rangeSlider1', 'Choose data range',
                  min= 0, max= max(dataset1$Length),
                  value= c(0, max(dataset1$Length)), round=T)

    }else if(input$data_choice== 'dataset2'){
      sliderInput('rangeSlider2', 'Choose data range',
                  min= 0, max= max(dataset2$Profit),
                  value= c(0, max(dataset2$Profit)), round=T)
    }
  })
```

Second, it seems the initial state of the renderUI input is null resulting in a data frame of dimension [0,0], which seems to halt any gvis output; yet it does not seem to affect plots generated by `renderPlot()`. By giving a conditional argument to `renderGvis()` it seems to bypass the issue:

```
output$view <- renderGvis({
    if(nrow(adjustPlot())!= 0){
      chart<-gvisBarChart(adjustPlot(), options= list(height= 700))
      return(chart)
    }
})
```

I do not know why this occurs (I'd love to hear it), but this solves the problem. The ui.R and the rest of server.R are the same as above just be sure to change all input variables. Hope this helps someone!